# Debian - no desktop environments to choose

Tags: linux, installation, debian

I am currently installing Debian 8 (debian8.1.0-amd64-i386-netlist.iso) with graphical installer from a USB drive . After partition selection, I don't see the option to select Desktop environments such as gnome. It only shows me "standard system utilities". No GUI is presented after installation.

Answer (score 2):

I am sure you installed Debian 8 using the Network Install image (*netinst* for short). Netinst images are meant to facilitate installation of a very basic Debian system from which you can install additional packages including desktop environments. They do not offer you to install a desktop environment (or any other additional packages for that matter).

You will have to download either the complete installer (4.4GB DVD image) or one of the DE-specific Live images if you want to have a GUI right after installation. Alternatively, you can install your preferred DE by running any of these commands (as root) in your current basic Debian session:

```
apt-get install task-gnome-desktop
apt-get install task-kde-desktop
apt-get install task-lxde-desktop
apt-get install task-xfce-desktop
```

Of course, you must already have a working Internet connection on the system.